# Turn pandas dataframe column into float

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I need to turn a pandas dataframe column into a float.  This float is taken from a larger csv file.  To get just the number I need to a dataframe I did:

```
m_df = pd.read_csv(input_file,nrows=1,header=None,skiprows=4)
m1=m_df.ix[:,1:1]
```

This gets me the dataframe with just the number I want in the first column.  How do I turn that number into a float?

Comment: and if you want the whole column as float [`m_df.astype('float')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype)

Comment: Sorry, I mean I need it not as a dataframe any more, just a float. ie `m1=7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float((m_df.ix[:,1:1]).values)`

For pandas dataframes, *type casting* works when done on the values, rather than the dataframe.